# MYSQL Remove duplication

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'test' and it has 4 columns, id,name,address,telephone.there are so many duplicate data. What i want is query to add telephone numbers to fist row with a '/' and delete other rows. please see the image.[image]

Comment: if there are name's / address's / id's which can have several phone's, you should split into 2 tables, define proper keys and you avoid duplicates automatically

Comment: This is not a source for people to give you code. What have you tried?

Comment: You should have defined a `UNIQUE KEY` when you created the table. Since you didn't, your punishment is the news that such a thing can pretty much only by done manually.

Comment: i already have data. i just want to remove duplicates.
eg -: i want to remove 2nd and 3rd rows but i want to add 2nd and 3rd rows phone numbers to first row with '/' to separate them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quick try.

You can do this to add all the phone numbers to the first record (comma separated, you can add a parm to change this to a slash instead but this would be an even worse idea)

```
UPDATE test a
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, address, GROUP_CONCAT(phone) AS AllPhone, MIN(id) AS MinId FROM test GROUP BY name, address) b
ON a.name = b.name
AND a.address = b.address
AND a.id = b.MinId
SET a.phone = b.AllPhone
```

Then delete the others with something like this

```
DELETE a
FROM test a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, address, MIN(id) AS MinId FROM test GROUP BY name, address) b
ON a.id = b.MinId
WHERE b.MinId IS NULL
```

Note that this going to give you a delimited list of phone numbers for a name / address which is a major pain to deal with in future, and a sign of a badly designed database.

Comment: Woow the query is amazing. thank you so much :)

Comment: delete command isn't working. nothing happens other than indicator animating in php myadmin.

Comment: Just knocked up a test table and tried it for myself and it works. Might well take quite a while depending on indexes

Comment: Oh, by way what version of phpmyadmin are you using. Some of the older versions seem to struggle with complex queries (ones which should work well, and do work if performed from a script).

Comment: I'm using xampp-macosx-1.7.3

Comment: I just checked it on windows (Wamp server). works like a charm.Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -2):

To delete the other data, use your PHPMuAdmin interface and you can delete them or build a an Admin page where you can dynamically edit and delete the data in your data base